# Owl Carousel run like a marquee

Tags: javascript, drupal-8

I have done this but it still works like a ticker. Please help me out thanks in advance.

```
var owl = $('.simple');
owl.once('js-trigger').owlCarousel({
    loop: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 650,
    autoplayHoverPause:true,
    responsiveClass:true,
    transitionStyle : "ease-in",
    responsive:{
        0:{
            items:1
        },
        600:{
            items:2
        },
        1000:{
            items:4
        },
    }
});
```